# NodeMCU not getting detected by Windows10

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

my NodeMCU (ESP8266) V3 is not getting detected by my windows 10 nothing happens when i attach the usb with it not even a blink of led or sound on windows that detects a device and it doesn't appear on device manager also it says to install CH340G driver on the back of the board my pc is full of drivers including the one i mentioned and installed all of them still nothing works can anyone help if they faced this issue before

product information:
idk much about the product but it says these on the back of the board
LoLin
new NodeMcu V3
and this at the front Ver 0.1 and its ESP8266MOD btw
and there are 2 buttons RST,FLASH

Comment: See https://docs.thingpulse.com/how-tos/install-drivers/ for how to install drivers. For a comparison of boards see https://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was resolved, I noticed that a component on the board wasn't well soldered and was a bit away from where it should be connected as I moved the component to where it should be it started working normally, for future readers if you have any problem with your board please make sure the components on the board are connected where they should be

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before. I can think of several issues including that you board is not working.

- If as you said LED won't even flash ones as it [should upon getting power](https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2018/10/introduction-to-nodemcu-v3.html), it is likely a hardware (HW) or wiring issue. You may still want to check it as below.
- Check if when you connect your board via USB a new device is detected. You can do it opening `Device Manager`, expanding `Ports (COM&LPT)` and checking what you see there before and after you connected the device. If nothing new appears, I would think of hardware or connectivity problem, otherwise a driver issue.
- For hardware problem easiest would be to check cable and usb port functionality. Simply trying to plug your board in different port or using different cable. Don't underestimate the last one, using dodgy cables or adapters (like to USB-C) can result in brownout of your ESP ending up without receiving enough power. I've faced the issue myself. Also an obvious one to make sure your cable has data lines and not just a charging cable. Also worth trying connecting it to another PC - captain obvious.
- Another check would be connecting 3.3 V source to the corresponding pin directly. Check if LED would blink and/or use FTDI programmer connected on RX-TX pins.

Unless I've missed something, further HW troubleshooting would require deeper knowledge of the board and advanced tools.